# Android - How to get the filtered audio and save as wav file

Tags: java, android, audio, filter, signal-processing

How do I get a filtered audio and output it as wav file?

I have already filtered the audio using IIR bandpass-filter and when I clicked on the "Play" button, I heard the audio being filtered but when I went to the .wav file it is the original audio and not the filtered audio.

Current code implementation

```
package com.example.audio;


import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.javasound.*;
import ddf.minim.javax.sound.sampled.*;
import ddf.minim.javax.sound.sampled.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.varma.samples.audiorecorder.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RecorderActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;// 44100; //18000
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO; //AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    private static final int PLAY_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO; //AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
    private static final int FREQUENCY_LEFT  = 2000; //Original:18000 (16 Dec)
    private static final int FREQUENCY_RIGHT  = 2000; //Original:18000 (16 Dec)
    private static final int AMPLITUDE_LEFT = 1;
    private static final int AMPLITUDE_RIGHT = 1;
    private static final int DURATION_SECOND = 10;
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    private static final float SWEEP_RANGE = 1000.0f;
    private static final int WRITE_NON_BLOCKING = 0;

    String store;
    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    double time;
    float[] buffer1;
    float[] buffer2;
    byte[] byteBuffer1;
    byte[] byteBuffer2;
    byte[] byteBufferFinal;
    int bufferIndex;
    short x;
    short y;
    AudioTrack audioTrack;

    Button btnPlay, btnStart, btnStop;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setButtonHandlers();
        enableButtons(false);

        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

        buffer1 = new float[(int) (DURATION_SECOND * SAMPLE_RATE)];
        buffer2 = new float[(int) (DURATION_SECOND * SAMPLE_RATE)];

        float f1 = 0.0f, f2 = 0.0f;

        for (int sample = 0, step = 0; sample < buffer1.length; sample++) {
            time = sample / (SAMPLE_RATE * 1.0);
            //f1 = (float)(FREQUENCY_LEFT + ((sample / (buffer1.length * 1.0)) * SWEEP_RANGE)); // frequency sweep
            //f2 = (float)(FREQUENCY_RIGHT + ((sample / (buffer1.length * 1.0)) * SWEEP_RANGE)); // frequency sweep
            f1 = FREQUENCY_LEFT; // static frequency
            f2 = FREQUENCY_RIGHT; // static frequency
            buffer1[sample] = (float) (AMPLITUDE_LEFT * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f1 * time));
            buffer2[sample] = (float) (AMPLITUDE_RIGHT * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f2 * time));
        }

        byteBuffer1 = new byte[buffer1.length * 2]; // two bytes per audio
                                                    // frame, 16 bits

        for (int i = 0, bufferIndex = 0; i < byteBuffer1.length; i++) {
            x = (short) (buffer1[bufferIndex++] * 32767.0); // [2^16 - 1]/2 =
                                                            // 32767.0
            byteBuffer1[i] = (byte) x; // low byte
            byteBuffer1[++i] = (byte) (x >>> 8); // high byte
        }

        byteBuffer2 = new byte[buffer2.length * 2];

        for (int j = 0, bufferIndex = 0; j < byteBuffer2.length; j++) {
            y = (short) (buffer2[bufferIndex++] * 32767.0);
            byteBuffer2[j] = (byte) y; // low byte
            byteBuffer2[++j] = (byte) (y >>> 8); // high byte

        }

        byteBufferFinal = new byte[byteBuffer1.length * 2];
        // LL RR LL RR LL RR
        for (int k = 0, index = 0; index < byteBufferFinal.length - 4; k = k + 2) {
            byteBufferFinal[index] = byteBuffer1[k]; // LEFT
                                                        // {0,1/4,5/8,9/12,13;...}
            byteBufferFinal[index + 1] = byteBuffer1[k + 1];
            index = index + 2;

            byteBufferFinal[index] = byteBuffer2[k]; // RIGHT
                                                        // {2,3/6,7/10,11;...}
            byteBufferFinal[index + 1] = byteBuffer2[k + 1];
            index = index + 2;
        }



        try {
            FileOutputStream ss = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER + "/source.txt");
            ss.write(byteBufferFinal);
            ss.flush();
            ss.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            Log.e("IO Error","Write source error.");
        }
    }

    private void setButtonHandlers() {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(startClick);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(stopClick);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)).setOnClickListener(playClick);
    }

    private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
        ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
    }

    private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
        enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
        enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
        enableButton(R.id.btnPlay, isRecording);
    }

    private String getFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{filepath}, null, null);

        store = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "AudioOriginal"          
            + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV;
        return store;
    }

    private String getTempFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

        if (tempFile.exists())
            tempFile.delete();

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    }


    private void startRecording() { 
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                (int) SAMPLE_RATE, PLAY_CHANNELS,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, byteBufferFinal.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

        audioTrack.write(byteBufferFinal, 0, byteBufferFinal.length);
        audioTrack.play();

        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
        recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    writeAudioDataToFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

        recordingThread.start();
    }

    float[][] deinterleaveData(float[] samples, int numChannels) {
        // assert(samples.length() % numChannels == 0);
        int numFrames = samples.length / numChannels;

        float[][] result = new float[numChannels][];
        for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
            result[ch] = new float[numFrames];
            for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
                result[ch][i] = samples[numChannels * i + ch];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    float[] interleaveData(float[][] data) {
          int numChannels = data.length;
          int numFrames   = data[0].length;

          float[] result = new float[numFrames];
          for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
              result[numChannels * i + ch] = data[ch][i];
            }
          }
          return result;
        }


    private int[] byteToShort(byte[] rawdata) {
      int[] converted = new int[rawdata.length / 2];

      for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
        // Wave file data are stored in little-endian order
        int lo = rawdata[2*i];
        int hi = rawdata[2*i+1];
        converted[i] = ((hi&0xFF)<<8) | (lo&0xFF);
      }
      return converted;
    }

    private float[] byteToFloat(byte[] audio) {
      return shortToFloat(byteToShort(audio));
    }

    /**
    * Convert int[] audio to 32 bit float format.
    * From [-32768,32768] to [-1,1] 
    * @param audio
    */
    private float[] shortToFloat(int[] audio) {
        Log.d("SHORTTOFLOAT","INSIDE SHORTTOFLOAT");
        float[] converted = new float[audio.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
            // [-32768,32768] -> [-1,1]
            converted[i] = audio[i] / 32768f; /* default range for Android PCM audio buffers) */
         System.out.println("Converted is " + converted[i]);
        }

        return converted;
    }

    private void writeAudioDataToFile() throws IOException {
        int read = 0;
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        String filename = getTempFilename();
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        FileOutputStream rs = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            rs = new FileOutputStream(getFilename().split(".wav")[0] + ".txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (null != os) {

           //BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);
            while (isRecording) {
    // decode and deinterleave stereo 16-bit per sample data
            //  float[][] signals = deinterleaveData(byteToFloat(data), 2);

    // filter data samples, updating the buffers with the filtered samples.
            //  bandpass.process(signals[0], signals[1]);

                  read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                    try {
                        os.write(data);
                        rs.write(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                os.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (null != recorder) {
            isRecording = false;

            audioTrack.flush();
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();

            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
        }

        copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
        deleteTempFile();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{getFilename()}, null, null);

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
    }

    private void deleteTempFile() {
        File file = new File(getTempFilename());
        file.delete();
    }

    private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
        int channels = 2;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];


        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
            totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

            while (in.read(data) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void playWaveFile() {
        String filepath = store;

        // define the buffer size for audio track
        int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        int bufferSize = 512;

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                (int) RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        int count = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                    fileInputStream);

            audioTrack.play();

            //BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);
            BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(550,20,44100);
            while ((count = dataInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) > -1)    
            {
            // decode and deinterleave stereo 16-bit per sample data
            // float[][] signals = deinterleaveData(byteToFloat(data), 2);

// filter data samples, updating the buffers with the filtered samples.
                //  bandpass.process(signals[0], signals[1]);

            // recombine signals for playback
            //audioTrack.write(interleaveData(signals), 0, count, WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
            // audioTrack.write(data, 0, count);            
            }

            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();
            dataInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
            long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)
            throws IOException {

        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1; // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        out.write(header, 0, 44);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener startClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isRecording = true;
                    startRecording();
                }

            });

            recordThread.start();
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            btnPlay.setEnabled(false);

        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener stopClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    stopRecording();
                    enableButtons(false);
                    btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                    // stop();
                }

            }, 100);

        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener playClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            playWaveFile();
            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);

            String filepath = store;

            final String promptPlayRecord = "PlayWaveFile()\n" + filepath;

            SpannableStringBuilder biggerText = new SpannableStringBuilder(promptPlayRecord);
            biggerText.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.05f), 0, promptPlayRecord.length(), 0);
            Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, biggerText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

I tried to put the filter under the method "writeAudioDataToFile", although it generates a filtered audio wav file, but it is a fast forwarded version. For eg: I recorded for about 5 secs but the .wav file will only play for 1 sec. Why is that so?

Am I right in putting the filter under the method "writeAudioDataToFile"? Otherwise, what steps should be taken to ensure that the filtered audio can be outputted as a .wav file.

Thanks for the advise guys!! Appreciated it

Libraries used

https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/effects/BandPass.java https://github.com/DASAR/Minim-Android/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/effects/IIRFilter.java

Comment: Well it definitely sounds like the actual write does not work. When you say it plays for 1 sec, do you mean that the 5 seconds of the audio is fast forwarded and you hear fast forwarded 5 seconds within the one second? If so, you might be setting sampling rate incorrectly for the record. Without looking at the code yet, make sure all the rates are correct with the original wav file.

Comment: @yun.cloud Yes I do mean that the 5 seconds of the audio is fast forwarded and you hear fast forwarded 5 seconds within the one second. All the sample rates are of 44100. :/

Comment: Why are you doing `byteBufferFinal[index] = byteBuffer1[k]; byteBufferFinal[index + 1] = byteBuffer1[k + 1]; index = index + 2;` ?